# Why GoLang Method gives Compile Error?

Tags: go, methods, compiler-errors

I am a trying the Methods in GoLang. I am a newbie so please correct me if I am asking dumb question. 
The [link](https://tour.golang.org/methods/2) says that we can write the Methods as normal Functions. But when I try following code it gives me compile error as

```
a.sq undefined (type MyFloat has no field or method sq)
```

The commented lines in following code are working as expected though.
Please help me. Following is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyFloat float64

func sq (f MyFloat) string {
    return fmt.Sprintln("The square is: ", f*f)
}

/*func (f MyFloat) sq() string {
    return fmt.Sprintln("The square is: ", f*f)
}*/

func main() {

    a := MyFloat(2.0)
    fmt.Println(a.sq())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `sq` as a function, not a method. If you want to attach `sq` to `MyFloat`, you should declare it like:

```
func (f MyFloat) sq() string {
    return fmt.Sprintln("The square is: ", f*f)
}
```

This way you will be able to do `a.sq()`.

Comment: Please check the link which tells us that how to write "Methods" as Normal Functions in GoLang. Also, In my code I have mentioned both the ways too.

Comment: What the tour is trying to convey is that methods are function. That does not mean that functions are method. Thus `func sq(f MyFloat) string` is not a method, and cannot be called in a `a.sq()` fashion.

Comment: So does it mean that the commented code in my question is the best way to use Methods?

Comment: yes. From the language specifications: `A method is a function with a receiver.`. The receiver is the part that goes between the `func` keyword and your function name. Beside the tour, I recommend reading [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods). The [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) is also an excellent resource to learn more about the language.

Comment: Yes, Agreed on that. Thank you very much for the help and links.